# How are you supposed to handle .net core service creation in terms of the dependency tree?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am now using this in my register services section. The problem here is the my services have their own dependencies, and maybe those will have dependencies. I dont see how I can solve that problem with this. for instance my location service requires the http client, the logger and two different repositories. I was expecting that having already registered those 4 dependencies as services, this would sort of take care of itself. Any suggestion would be massively appreciated.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // db related
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("VoloDataBaseConnectionString");
        var dbContext = new DbContext(connectionString);
        services.AddSingleton<IDbContext>(dbContext);
        services.AddScoped(typeof(Repository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

        // utilities
        services.AddSingleton(new HttpClient());
        services.AddSingleton(new Logger(dbContext));

        // bll services
        services.AddSingleton(
            new LocationService(
                new HttpClient(),
                new Logger(dbContext),
                new Repository<Country>(dbContext),
                new Repository<Location>(dbContext)
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Register them as types, not instances. e.g. `services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>()` instead of `services.AddSingleton(new HttpClient())`.

Comment: @Valuator why is that please?

Comment: When you register the types, the DI system can auto-inject the dependencies in the constructors, whenever a new instance needs to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was expecting that having already registered those 4 dependencies as services, this would sort of take care of itself.

It will take care of itself. You just have to make use of the container's Auto-Wiring abilities:

```
services.AddScoped<LocationService>();
```

Do note that, to prevent [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/), you should make sure that components do not depend on other components with a shorter lifestyle. For instance, do not let a `Singleton` component depend on a `Scoped` component. For that reason, `LocationService` should *not* be registered as `Singleton`, but rather as `Scoped` or `Transient`.